# How do I create e-commerce products without creating a page for each product?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I create the visualization of the products of an e-commerce, without creating different pages for the products?

I'm a beginner developer and I kindly ask for input to move forward.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, write your question in English

Comment: This would still be closed as "not enough focus" even if [it was in English](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=Come%20posso%20fare%20per%20creare%20la%20visualizzione%20dei%20prodotti%20di%20un%20ecommerce%2C%20ma%20senza%20creare%20pagine%20diverse%20per%20i%20tanti%20prodotti.%20Sono%20alle%20prime%20armi%20con%20javascript%20e%20con%20html%20e%20css%20sto%20perfezionando.%20Chiedo%20gentilmente%20degli%20input%20per%20andare%20avanti.%20Grazie%20in%20anticipo.&op=translate)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

make a file to show the product, and always when you need to show a product call that file.
this means the code is the same for all products, 1, 2, 4000, doesnt matter.

this means you have to have the products on a database or store in an array of some kind.  and then every time you call the product file, the product file will have a way to identified that product, and then show the properties of that product.

wordpress is a good example, uses php, but the idea is the same.